# Delay on Java.Clip Mute Controls

Tags: java, audio, controls, javasound, clip

So i'm writing this sort of game in Java where you play like Guitar Hero. I can play both parts of the song (the song and the guitar) and so far so good. 
Next, i needed to mute the guitar part when someone missed a key. The problem is, there's a 1sec or so delay from the moment i mute the Clip until it actually mutes. 
How can this delay be fixed?

```
    try {
        audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("guitar.wav"));
        guitar = AudioSystem.getClip();
        guitar.open(audioIn);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    guitar.start();

    volume = (BooleanControl) guitar.getControl(BooleanControl.Type.MUTE);
```

An in the game loop:

```
    if (missedKey()) {
        volume.setValue(true);
     } else {
        volume.setValue(false);
     }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Don't use clip, use input streams/output streams. Then output zeroes to the stream to mute which will be potentially much more responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up following Radiodef's answer and use byte streams. I have a buffer filled with 0's and i either output that or the normal audio to the stream.